# My Chines characters converts to extra character while making order in paypal how to display item name in default language.?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, payment-gateways

When i made any order of chines named item its get converted in extra character hwile it redirected to paypal site. how can i handle multi language in paypal [image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a bug in Paypal module you are using, and as such should be reported in module's issue queue, not here.

Comment: so what can i do for this issue.? any suggestions?

Comment: Go to the project page of module you are using, find "issues" or  "bugs" link, and file a report. Or, if it's your code, post that code, and ask Paypal team how should you send it so they can receive it properly. Then we could answer what's the difference between your code and what Paypal needs from you.